# Latest Solution for Aspire D270

Tags: intel-graphics, hdmi, acer

I was just given an Acer Aspire D270 (Atom N2600 and 1GB of RAM) netbook with a broken screen and would like to turn it into a streaming (and occasional USB thumb drive) video player for my projector (via the HDMI output). Searching for others who have installed Ubuntu on it I find a variety of graphics chip problems (it has the GMA 3650, apparently) and solutions mentioned but, since they are older posts, was wondering if the best approach may well have changed since they were written. Thought it would make sense to ask for the input of those more knowledgeable before proceeding. Thanks very much.

Update:

Installed 14.04 and it has none of the resolution issues the old posts mentioned. Unfortunately, video playback is extremely choppy. Probably a result of no dedicated graphics driver as the earlier posts point out.

Comment: I think your best approach would be to follow their steps and then post what's not working here so someone can try and help.

Comment: Let me be a bit more directed: should I stick with 12.04 (seems to be the most recommended version from those old posts) or would trying the latest version make more sense? I have no idea what might have changed in the intervening generations that this wimpy hardware might not be able to cope with.

Comment: I feel like you might be better off trying 14.04 first and then heading back to 12.04 if it doesn't work. The newer kernel in 14.04 could have been patched/updated to work to your advantage. Wish I had a more concrete answer for yoou though.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an Ubuntu related question, or answer, but... [you can replace a laptop screen for as little as $50.](https://www.laptopscreen.com/) (search for D270). I did this with my Thinkpad T510 recently.

I also have that netbook but not with HDMI output, it's pretty slow. It can't play youtube videos full screen without getting choppy so I don't think you're going to be very impressed with it as a projector. It can run a few open tabs in chrome and that's about it, and I think that's after I upgraded it to 2GB.

It might not be worth the time or money :(, I mean for about $100 you can get a new Asus 7" tablet that'll have more horsepower than this.

Comment: OP is asking if the steps to get a laptop with a GMA3650 chip to boot sucessfully on Ubuntu have changed.

Comment: @amanthethy Thank you. I can't help with with video card issues, which appear to be resolution limitations (who's workarounds are in 'who knows what state'), but I can comment on my experience with that platform, how to fix a broken display, and the platform's fitness for the intended application.

Comment: Final performance certainly would be relevant, but I've no desire to replace the screen. Thanks for the information, though. My friend used to stream video on it, but that was under Windows 7 so that'd be with an appropriate graphics driver presumably. Certainly was a terribly slow device overall. No idea how he put up with it for so long.